# Ошибка при загрузке модуля для opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart, cms, opencart2.0

[image: Изображение 2]

[image: Изображение 1]

Версия opencart 2.3
Название модуля localcopy (движок на vps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить расширение [Dom](https://www.php.net/en/dom)

Debian / Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo apt-get install php-dom
```

Centos / Fedora / Red Hat:

```
yum install php-xml
```

`sudo apt-get install php*-` Вместо * надо указать версию вашего php

Пример

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom
```

Comment: Вы ходит ошибка: Package 'php-dom' has no installation candidate

Comment: попробуйте сначала установить php-xml (php-dom часть это библиотеки). sudo apt-get install php-xml, а потом sudo apt-get install php-dom

Comment: Надо было указать версию php (Ваш ответ правильный)!!!